# Convert GIF to Video in Android

Tags: java, android, video, gif

I want to convert GIF file to video file, I searched for it but couldn't find any library for it. Does any one know how to do it ?

Comment: im convert two img and audio in video, using ffmpeg mb sample help u=) https://github.com/v4ekmarev/MergerLibrary/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/vladlen/mergerlibrary/Merger.java

Answer (score 1):

There is library [android-ffmpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java)

In short, there is method in FfmpegController called `convertImageToMP4 (Clip mediaIn, int duration, String outPath, ShellCallback sc)`. I think it should do, what you want.

Also, please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233394/how-to-convert-gif-to-mp4-is-it-possible) answer for more details.

Comment: I think it's for Image to MP4, i want GIF to MP4(or any other video format)

Comment: This function uses command for ffmpeg converter. Base on it, you can create your own which will be use this command `ffmpeg -f gif -i infile.gif outfile.mp4`